# How to change UAD rate to CAD rate in hive table

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, calculator

I have a hive table and The table rate is based on UAD. I want to calculate the Rate based on CAD dollar

Select (select rate from rate where currency_code = 'CAD') as c_rate , c_rate/r.rate
from rate r

Select (select rate from rate where currency_code = 'CAD') as c_rate , c_rate/r.rate
from rate r

Actual result:
cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'rate' in expression specification (state=42000,code=4000

Expect Result:

c_rate/rate[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a conditional aggregation using `max` window function.

```
select t.*,max(case when currency_code = 'CAD' then UAD_RATE end) over()/uad_rate
from tbl t
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, I have other table calls CAD_rate table that has the same columns with the rate table and I need to compare the rate value from these two tables

Select count(*)
from rate r
join CAD_Rate c 
on r.currency_code=c.currency_code
where round ((max (case when w.currency_code = 'CAD' then w.rate end) over()/w.rate) ,8)=c.rate I get max not find error message "Invalid column reference 'max':"